# Django filter not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-filter

my filter isn't working Whenever I access http://localhost:8080/payables/invoices/?status=NOT_PAID It just returns all the invoices. I have no runtime error, the parameter I enter simply seems to be ignored. I really don't understand, other than that, it works well.

**views.py**

```
class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
    filter_backend = filters.DjangoFilterBackend
    filter_fields = ('status','supplier',)

    def list(self,request,):
        queryset = Invoice.objects.filter()
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Invoice.objects.filter()
        invoice = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoice)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class InvoiceItemViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    serializer_class = InvoiceItemSerializer

    def list(self,request,invoice_pk=None):
        queryset = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(invoice=invoice_pk)
        serializer = InvoiceItemSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def retrieve(self,request,pk,invoice_pk):
        queryset = InvoiceItem.objects.filter(pk=pk,invoice=invoice_pk)
        invoice_item = get_object_or_404(queryset,pk=pk)
        serializer = InvoiceItemSerializer(invoice_item)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
#viewset
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from payables.views import InvoiceViewSet,InvoiceItemViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'invoices', InvoiceViewSet,base_name='invoices')

invoice_item_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router,r'invoices',lookup='invoice')
invoice_item_router.register(r'items', InvoiceItemViewSet, base_name='invoice_items')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^',include(invoice_item_router.urls))
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are explicitly creating the queryset and hence the filter backend is never used:

```
queryset = Invoice.objects.filter()
```

I suggest looking at [`ModelViewSet`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset). In that case you just have to pass `queryset` at the view level and rest will be taken care of.

Comment: Hi, how do I pass queryset correctly to the "view level"? should I add another argument to the list function inside InvoiceViewSet? For instance def list(self,request,queryset):?

Comment: Are you using `ModelViewSet`. If yes then you can follow the documentation and see how it declares the queryset.

Answer (score 2):

instead of  `queryset = Invoice.objects.filter()`

with `queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).filter()`

Comment: can you use self on the top level?

Answer (score 1):

instead of `queryset = Invoice.objects.filter()`

use `queryset = self.get_queryset()`

`self.get_queryset()` returns the filtered object list